# Is there a way to list the java version of all my maven dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

Consider I have a maven java project that I wish to use the minimum version of Java possible. It has a number of dependencies. Is there a way I can see what the version of java used to compile the jar is for all of the resolved dependencies?

Comment: I don't think there is a way but would be interesting in finding out!

Comment: Since a jar is simply a collection of class files, you'd probably have to look at each class individually as those could have been compiled with different versions.

Comment: @rethab I only see that as a risk in a fat-jar (AKA one-jar), and I don't expect far jars to pop up as Maven dependencies. I'd say it is a safe assumption to only check one class in the jar to get the answer.

Comment: You can try compiling the project with different java versions and you will see which one works.

Comment: Hi @vitro. I can certainly do something like that, but I see this as a bit of an anti-pattern. Here's why. Let's say I've inadvertently pulled in a dependency that I don't need and it is one version of Java higher than the rest. So I up my pom to that version. I then finish my development and remove said dependency after seeing from my reports that I don't need it. Since I never identified that it was that exact jar that caused me to move up a version, I've artificially increased the version requirement of my artifact. By identifying the dependency, I can make smart decisions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run `mvn site` on your project, one of the default reports (the 'Dependencies' report) generated will give you details about your dependencies.

After running `mvn site` find the `target/site/dependencies.html` file and open it in a browser. The section entitled "Dependency File Details" has a table in which one of the columns is the JDK revision used to compile a given dependency.

The maven-project-info-reports-plugin is what is responsible for generating this information. If you just want to generate that single html report from the command line you can do so with the following command

`mvn project-info-reports:dependencies`

The report will be located in the same place as with `mvn site` at `target/site/dependencies.html`

Comment: Awesome! Not only does it break it down for me as I had hoped, but it has a summary at the bottom that tells me what the minimum jdk I need.